# Powershell -Signer command not working when trying to create child certificate from root certificate

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to create a child certificate from root certificate in powershell ([MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1)). Unfortunately the `-Signer` command is not working. What to do?

The command I am trying to run is:

```
$rootcert = ( Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\My\"64F613A8CC7000B78117775EACEE5B27A0A09F26" )

New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname "localhost" -Signer $rootcert
```

I get the following error:

**New-SelfSignedCertificate : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Signer'.**

I am using the windows 8.1 & Powershell version:

**PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005**

Kindly help?

Comment: Runs PS_ise in debug mode, take breakpoint on second line, then check what store your variable `$rootcert` and pipe it to `Get-member` cmdlet to know what type it receive. Add info in post.

Comment: That documentation is for ASP.NET Core, and `-Signer` parameter is available for Windows 10 and Server 2016 only - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps

Comment: Ok now the question is how to use -signer in windows 8.1. Please help.??